# Python Scrapy Print Item Keys as Header in CSV

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I have a scrapy project I'm working on and I'm trying to export data to a csv file using a pipeline and I would like to print the item keys as the first row of the csv file.  My pipeline code is below (I can post more code if necessary but I imagine this would suffice).  Thanks in advance.

```
import csv

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('items.csv','wb'))

    def process_item(self,item,pfr):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item[key] for key in item.keys()])
        return item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy already adds header to csv export if you are outputting csv via:

```
scrapy crawl spidername --output results.csv
```

If you want to do it manually in a the pipeline you can create file and write headers in pipelines [open_spider()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#open_spider) method, which will execute all of the code in it when the spider opens.

Something like:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    header_keys = MyItem.fields.keys()
    self.csvwriter.writerow(header_keys)
```

Comment: This I know.  I am not outputting via the command line, though.

Comment: @Jeff Then you can most likely do it in the pipeline. You can read the keys your item has and write them once to your csv file. See my edit for more details.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I didn't see a way to do it in the __init__ since I wasn't passing an item but this looks great. Thanks.